# Nativescript - setting the color of an ActionItem icon (Android)

Tags: nativescript

I've got an action item defined as (Android)

`<ActionItem tap="onReload" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_refresh"  android.position="actionBar" />`

It displays an icon - how can I set the color?

I'm got the following in the manifest file - but that changes the color of the text only.

`<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>`

Comment: What do you mean the color of the icon ? You can set the color of the entire ActionBar via the background-color css property (https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#styling)

Comment: ok - can I change the font of the action item - maybe i can use FontAwesome for the icons then.

Comment: Yes you could be in my experience it is not a good approach for the navigation icons, since those icons can be different in different screen sizes while the FontAwesome will not scale as good as a real image/icon would.